# ConTeXt: Flush right formula numbers in cases environment

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, context, cases

I would like to have the formula numbers of the cases environment **flush right** like regular formulas (not at a fixed distant from the cases like it is by default with the default setting `numberdistance=2.5\emwidth`). How can I do that?

```
\starttext

\startplaceformula
    \startformula
        \startcases
            \NC x = 1 \NR[+]
            \NC y = 1 \NR[+]
        \stopcases
    \stopformula
\stopplaceformula

\stoptext
```

[image]

What I want (but with the left bracket):

```
\starttext

\startplaceformula
    \startformula
        \startalignment[n=1]
            \NC x = 1 \NR[+]
            \NC y = 1 \NR[+]
        \stopalignment
    \stopformula
\stopplaceformula

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried all sorts of things now, but I can't even get the latter equations numbers to flush right, on TL14. Which version are you running?

Comment: As I replied to a similar question on the context mailing list, this is currently not possible.

Comment: @morbusg: Sorry I forgot to add the option `[n=1]` in `\startalignment`, that is why the equations were not flush right.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by hand.

```
\starttext

\startplaceformula
  \startformula
        \rlap{\hskip6.5cm \Bigg\{}
        \startalignment[n=1,location=middle]
            \NC x = 1 \NR[+]
            \NC y = 1 \NR[+]
          \stopalignment
    \stopformula
\stopplaceformula

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: On ConTeXt version 2016.05.19 (from TeX Live 2017), I get this:
"tex error on line 8 in file /tmp/xr0jUK/texweb.tex: ! Improper \halign inside $$'s
\math_both_eqalign_no_aligned ...fi \fi #1\halign \ifcase \eqalignmode \or t...
l.8 \startalignment[n=1,location=middle]"

Comment: @Maggyero That's from TeX live 2016.  My answer assumes that you are using the latest ConTeXt standalone.