# Subformula numbering

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, context

I can't get cases subformula to work properly. My MWE, inspired from the wiki and the My Way "Using `\startalign` and friends" by Aditya Mahajan, is :

```
\starttext
\placeformula
\startformula
    \startcases
      \NC x = a \NR[+]
      \NC y = b \NR[+]
    \stopcases
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

This only prints (2) on the right of the whole cases system. If I use `\placesubformula`, the behavior remains exactly the same.

Has there been a change in the behavior since the documents were written ?

---

EDIT

Since the question was marked as a duplicate of [ConTeXt: Flush right formula numbers in cases environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201633/context-flush-right-formula-numbers-in-cases-environment), I must say the answer provided there works but does not seem satisfying. I first rewrite the code suggested by Henri Menke here :

```
\startformula
    \rlap{\hskip6.5cm \Bigg\{}
    \startalignment[n=1,location=middle]
        \NC x = 1 \NR[+]
        \NC y = 1 \NR[+]
    \stopalignment
\stopformula
```

When I use ConTeXt (or LaTeX or another typesetting system with the same philosphy) I think I should not have to manage by hand the placement of the braces (with the `\hskip` command) everytime I use the cases environment within columns, or very long equations, and so on. This is why I don't find the solution proposed by Henri Menke to be satisfying in a long-term usage.

Comment: @Sebastiano This is a complete and compilable context document

Comment: The article you are quoting is 12 years old, it is quite likely that there were breaking changes in the meantime.  It might be a good idea to ask about this on the mailing list.

Comment: I sent a mail a week ago, and still don't have an answer. Is there any newer documentation / other contact ? It seems unlikely that modern ConTeXt don't manage that...

Comment: This answer seems to work with current context: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426482/36296  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZLOn.png

Comment: This answer works for different formula numbers, thank you. However I think this is some kind of "handmade" solution and I imagine there should be a "real" ConTeXt-oriented way to solve this...

Comment: Please note that the `cases` environment is not meant for listing subformulas. It is meant for, well, listing cases. This is the same in LaTeX (amsmath).